# My spring boot project cannot create table in database

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to connect my spring boot project and it's working without any problem but it wont create tables in my database. I think it has something to do with this message in my terminal: "2023-03-08T19:03:42.090+03:30  INFO 13720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces."
It creates table successfully in other projects but it has problem in this one.

1.Entity

```
package com.myproject.ecommerce.entity;

import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @NotBlank
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Product name cannot be blank!!")
    @Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false)
    String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Product price cannot be blank!!")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Product price cannot be negative!!")
    @Column(name = "product_price", nullable = false)
    long price;

    @NotBlank(message = "Product description cannot be blank!!")
    @Column(name = "product_description", nullable = false)
    String description;

    @NotBlank(message = "Product seller id cannot be blank!!")
    @Column(name = "product_seller_id", nullable = false)
    long seller_id;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "products")
    Set<Category> categories;
}
```

2.repository

```
package com.myproject.ecommerce.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.myproject.ecommerce.entity.Product;


public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
    
}
```

3.application

```
package com.myproject.ecommerce;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class ECommerceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

4.pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>e-commerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>e-commerce</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I expect in my terminal something like that:
Hibernate:

```
alter table course_student
   drop constraint FKlmj50qx9k98b7li5li74nnylb
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table course_student
   drop constraint FK4xxxkt1m6afc9vxp3ryb0xfhi
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table grade
   drop constraint FK7e8ca7hfmrpruicqhocskjlf2
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table grade
   drop constraint FK5secqnjjwgh9wxk4h1xwgj1n0
```

Hibernate:

```
drop table course cascade
```

Hibernate:

```
drop table course_student cascade
```

Hibernate:

```
drop table grade cascade
```

Hibernate:

```
drop table student cascade
```

Hibernate:

```
drop table users cascade
```

Hibernate:

```
create table course (
   id  bigserial not null,
    code varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null,
    subject varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
create table course_student (
   student_id int8 not null,
    course_id int8 not null,
    primary key (course_id, student_id)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
create table grade (
   id  bigserial not null,
    score varchar(255) not null,
    course_id int8 not null,
    student_id int8 not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
create table student (
   id  bigserial not null,
    birth_date date not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
create table users (
   id  bigserial not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    username varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table grade
   add constraint UKm4rb6f2efyvns11hpghb8qilv unique (student_id, course_id)
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table users
   add constraint UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6 unique (username)
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table course_student
   add constraint FKlmj50qx9k98b7li5li74nnylb
   foreign key (course_id)
   references course
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table course_student
   add constraint FK4xxxkt1m6afc9vxp3ryb0xfhi
   foreign key (student_id)
   references student
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table grade
   add constraint FK7e8ca7hfmrpruicqhocskjlf2
   foreign key (course_id)
   references course
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table grade
   add constraint FK5secqnjjwgh9wxk4h1xwgj1n0
   foreign key (student_id)
   references student
```

Comment: You have also set this parameter spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto correctly?

Comment: yes, it's working on my other project

Comment: Also create or update, right?

Comment: yes it should work properly

Comment: you have declared long, but your migrations have int

Comment: Do you have @EnableJpaRepositories in your main application class?